# Google App Engine - Sudden increase in latency

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have seen a sudden latency increase in our application on Google App Engine latency within the past few hours. The logs show that requests fail with message "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.", with no stack-trace or any other relevant information. Users get an empty page with message "Rate exceeded.". No changes have been done to the application that correlate to this spike in latency.

The application is therefore down, with no information from app engine that can help point to the source of the latency.

We have filed a issue in the issuer tracker, no luck in getting response yet.

Does anyone have ideas on what we could do to deal with this kind of situation?

[image: Screenshot showing increased lattency]

**Update**

The problem went away after 3 hours as suddenly as it came, and without any intervention on our part. Since there is consensus on min_idle_instances, we have decided to leave all the setting as they have always been so that we can see if this ever happens again. If it does happen, we will have an opportunity to test this by making the suggested changes, and post an update here.

Here is a screen shot for the entire incident:
[image: Screen shot of the entire incident]

Comment: Have you specified min_idle_instances in your app.yaml file?

Comment: Yes @ParthMehta. Makes sense. But, wouldn't min_iddle_instances affect latency of first requests to a new instance? In this case the whole application was inaccessible for 3 hours with no more than usual load. The problem went away as suddenly as it came after 3 hours, with no intervention on our part. We have had the same settings app.yaml for more than 12 months

Comment: Sounds like it could be something to do with GCP outage, take a look at Google service status page: https://status.cloud.google.com/ and see if any outages match with your outage timing.

Comment: Yes @ParthMehta, thank you. There was actually an network issue in Bulgaria whose timing correspond with timing of our downtime almost perfectly. I can't think of how a network issue in Bulgaria would affect latency of an app in US, strange. https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-networking/19023

Answer (score 1):

The comment that @Parth Mehta added is useful and it made me think of what could be causing your issues.

I'm thinking that maybe your increased latency is due to not having idle instances ready for the requests as they increase and come in, so when requests increase a bit is taken until the new instances are ready and there might be your latency cause.

Setting enough min_idle_instances might alleviate the 500's as they would be warm and ready for the requests.

If this doesn't solve your issue I would recommend creating a case with GCP Support and we will surely be able to assist you more.

Try it and let us know.

Comment: The application was inaccessible for 3 hours, the problem went away as suddenly as it came, with no intervention on our part. We have had the same appengine-web.xml setting for more than 12 months. We have decided to leave the settings as they are so that if this ever happens again, we could attempt to modify settings to see if the problem resolved. It seems this is the only way to test the hypothesis. Thank you

Comment: Hi Stefan. I had created an issue with GCP Support, and they did respond, thank you. It looks like there was an issue whose timing almost perfectly correspond with the timing of our downtime: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-networking/19023 . I have asked GCP Support if they can confirm whether that was the root cause, in which case that will be the answer.